# A page stays empty (routing problem) in Angular

Tags: angular

When I click on the "Portfolio" hyperlink.

[image]

The Portfolio page isn't display (see below)

[image]

I don't completely understand the routing system.

Here is how my files are structured

[image]

In the folder -> ***Identity***

*identity.component.html*

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

*singin.component.html*

```
<div
  class="top-bar"
  style="background-color: green; width: 100%; height: 98px;"
></div>

<h1 style="text-align: center">Singin page</h1>

<div style="text-align: center">
  <a href="portfolio">Portfolio</a>
</div>
```

In the folder -> ***Admin**

*admin.component.html*

```
<div class="header"></div>
<input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu" id="openSidebarMenu" />
<label for="openSidebarMenu" class="sidebarIconToggle">
  <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
  <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
  <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
</label>
<div id="sidebarMenu">
  <ul class="sidebarMenuInner">
    <li>
      <a routerLink="portfolio"> <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Portfolio </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

*portfolio.component.html*

```
<h1>Portfolio page</h1>
```

*app.routing.module*

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'identity',
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,

    children: [
      {
        path: 'portfolio',
        component: PortfolioComponent,
      },
    ],
  },

  {
    path: 'identity',
    component: IdentityComponent,

    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'singin',
      },
      {
        path: 'singin',
        component: SinginComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

*app.component.html*

```
<router-outlet> </router-outlet>
```

I share you  my code on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fu2hak?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`routerLink`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink). See updated [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1q3kft?file=src%2Fapp%2Fviews%2Fidentity%2Fview%2Fsingin%2Fsingin.component.html).